# Объединить 2 MediaStreamAudioSourceNode на JS

Tags: javascript, web-audio

Есть звонилка на webRTC. Требуется записывать разговоры средствами JS.
Для записи использую библиотеку recorder.js. Есть два потока:

```
var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var stream2 = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(document.getElementById('main_audio_remote').captureStream());
```

input - поток с микрофона, stream2 - звук собеседника.
Следующим кодом у меня получается записать либо первый поток, либо второй.

```
recorder = new Recorder(input);
recorder.record();
```

Вопрос: как объединить эти два потока?

На всякий случай весь код:

```js
                var audio_context;
                var recorder;

                function startUserMedia(stream) {
                    /*var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                    var stream2 = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(document.getElementById('main_audio_remote').captureStream());
                    stream2.connect(input.destination);*/

                    /*var options = {
                        mediaStream : document.getElementById('main_audio_remote').captureStream()
                    };
                    var source = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(audio_context, options);
                    source.connect(audio_context.destination);*/
                    //var merger = audio_context.createChannelMerger(2);
                    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                    var stream2 = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(document.getElementById('main_audio_remote').captureStream());

                    //merger.connect(input);
                   // merger.connect(stream2);

                    recorder = new Recorder(input);
                    console.log('Recorder initialised.');
                }

                function startRecording(button) {
                    recorder && recorder.record();
                    console.log('Recording...');
                }

                function stopRecording(button) {
                    recorder && recorder.stop();
                    console.log('Stopped recording.');
                    createDownloadLink();
                    recorder.clear();
                }

                function createDownloadLink() {
                    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
                        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        var au = document.createElement('audio');
                        var hf = document.createElement('a');

                        au.controls = true;
                        au.src = url;
                        hf.href = url;
                        hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
                        hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
                        li.appendChild(au);
                        li.appendChild(hf);
                        recordingslist.appendChild(li);
                    });
                }

                window.onload = function init() {
                    try {
                        // webkit shim
                        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
                        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                        audio_context = new AudioContext;
                        console.log('Audio context set up.');
                        console.log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
                    }

                    //navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
                    //.then(startUserMedia);

                    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
                        console.log('No live audio input: ' + e);
                    });
                };
```

Comment: Можно попробовать так:
**recorder = new Recorder(input);
recorder.record();
recorder2 = new Recorder(stream2);
recorder2.record();**
Если не получится, то объявление второго **audiocontex**t скорее всего решит проблему.

Comment: @Это не весь код, я не нашёл, как Вы получаете аудиопоток собеседника. Идея, как объединить уже есть, но желательно, чтобы я знал этот важный момент.